# How in JPA mappe into one column values of two other columns?

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I am using JPA, and in my DB I have a table `student` with columns: id, firstname and firstAndLastname

So I did an `Entity` to mappe data, I can get `lastname` from another table, but I don't persist it as there is no columns lastname in DB.

How to store in column `firstAndLastname` that is concatenation of firstname and lastname and store it in specific column, example : firstname : John, lastname : Doe => firstAndLastname : JohnDoe

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstname;

@Transient
private String lastname;

@Column(name = "firstAndLastname")
private String firstLastname;
```

I tried this (and not working) :

```
public String getFirstLastname() {
    return this.firstname+ this.lastname;
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You have this `firstAndLastname` column in database?

Comment: Yes @code_mechanic I have it

Comment: What is saved there?

Comment: It's supposed to contain concatenation of firstnames and lastnames

Comment: If you are saving value there, then why are you getting it by concatenation in the getter?

Comment: @code_mechanic so far, this column is still empty, I need to start to store there

Comment: You just need to set the value to this property at the time of saving and you would have value in database. You question is little unclear.

Comment: @code_mechanic I maybe didn't express the problem correctly, but the idea is to store in firstAndLastname  a concatenation of firstname and lastname, I'll try a setter

Comment: Just try to set this property with desired value and JPA will persist it in db, you may not be setting it in your save code.

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't figured out how to persist data to the database, that's where you need to start. You don't persist data in the JPA itself, that's just the structure for the object.  You will build an instance of the Student object in another Class, set the values, and persist it to the database.

You would set that firstLastName value where/when you are creating an instance of your Student.

This is just a rough explanation. Not explicit code for you.
You would have a class like:

```
public class SaveStudentService {
    public saveStudent(){
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName("test");
        student.setLastName("lastTest");
        student.setFirstLast(student.getFirstName + " "+ student.getLastName);
        
        studentRepo.save(student);
    }
}
```

You'll have your normal getters and setters in your Student class...

```
public Student getfirstName() {return this.firstName;}
public Student setfirstName(String firstName) {return this.firstName = firstName;}

public Student getfirstLast() {return this.firstLastName;}
public Student setfirstName(String firstLastName) {return this.firstLastName = firstLastName;}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Genetate getters/setter for all properties of the Entity.
2. Instantiate the object to save: `Student student = new Student(1,"Mario","Rossi");`
3. Call the setter :  `student.setFirstLastName(student.getFirstName()+student.getLastName());`
4. `myStudentService.save(student);`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend 2 approaches:

1. If you instantiate object by constructor:

```
public Student(final Integer id, final String firstname, final String lastname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.firstLastname = String.join(firstname, lastname);
}
```

2. By setter:

```
public void setFirstLastname(final String firstName, final String lastName) {
    this.firstLastname = String.join(firstName, lastName);
}
```

3. In addition you can also use Spring AOP and advice `save` method on your repository but it's less readable and more difficult to maintenance.

```
@Before("execution(* com.package.StudentRepository.save(..))")
public void updateFirstLastName(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    final Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();
    // find Student.class object and update firstLastName field
}
```

Either way - don't perform concatenation outside `Student` class because it leads to boilerplate and it's harder to maintenance.
But IMHO the best approach is to store `firstName` and `lastName` separately in database and use SQL `CONCAT` function if needed.